# Best way to manage a login workflow in a mobile app

Tags: android, ios, mobile, authentication, workflow

I have some apps in Android that requires a login, but i'm not sure if i'm doing the login workflow in the correct way.

Basically, I have two activities LoginActivity and MainActivity. My default launcher activity is the MainActivity and in it's onCreate method I check if the user is logged in, if not I start the LoginActivity.

Another solution is make LoginActivity as default launcher activity and in it's onCreate method check if the user is logged in, if true, start the MainActivity.

Are two different architectures, and I like to know what is the best.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't imagine there's a "correct" way to do this. Both of your suggestions seem quite valid. Just do what works best for you, your app, and your users. If there were an "exact" way to program everything, there would be no need for programmers!

Comment: @NoChinDeluxe thanks for your answer

Answer (score 4):

The second one works best for me as i make the Login Activity act as a splash screen too, this gives me time to check for logged in user, and then whether to show the Login screen or to move to the MainActivity. This gives a more elegant user experience. But again, that's what works best for me. As what @NochinDeluxe already said, there is no "One Way" to do programming.

Answer (score 4):

You can also go for a third approach. Make a splash screen where you can also initialise any libraries if required. Splash screen would then decide which activity to launch